# Python: Print only one value of an SQL query result set

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://myusername:mypassword@127.0.0.1:1433/AQOA_Core')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT Distributor FROM Product""")
for row in result:
    print row[0]
connection.close()
```

The above code returns a result set as:

```
FRANCETV
GAUMONT
M6SND
PATHE
STUDIOCANAL
TF1
WARNER
```

What if I want to print just one value without changing the query?

Tried `print row[0][1]`, `print row[0:1]` This was tried to print just the first value `FRANCETV`

Basically I want to be able to print each one of the values in the result set seperately without making changes to the query.

Comment: What does `print result[0][0]` return?

Comment: `S
E
G
G
W
O
M
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect.py", line 6, in <module>
    print row[0][0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: That's not PyMsSQL at all.

Comment: oops! That what I thought it was.

Comment: It's SQLAlchemy. I would look at their docs for the equivalent fetchone function.

Comment: I thought PyMsSQL was a part of SQLAlchemy. Thanks for the info though. I will look into the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to access the data by:

```
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT Distributor FROM Product""")
result_list = result.fetchall()  
result_list[0][0]
connection.close()
```

Comment: This does the same thing as my code. What if I wanted to print only 1 value?

Comment: Works perfect. I make necessary changes in result_list to print different values of the result set.

Comment: Good! The fetchall() method returns a list of tuples, which you can access and modify like you intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the pymssql docs, you'll see the cursor object has a [`fetchone()`](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#pymssql.Cursor.fetchone) method.

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT Distributor FROM Product""")
    first_row = cursor.fetchone()
    print first_row
```

Comment: I am using `pymssql` for the connection.

Comment: @TauseefHussain Does this work for you? If not, what is the error?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

Comment: You said you're using pymssql? Can you edit your main post to show exactly what you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

```
 file = open("testfile.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
 mycursor.execute('SELECT * from COMPANY')
 myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
 counter = 0
 y = 0
   for x in myresult:
   y = 0
   while y < 3:
      print(y)
      file.write("%s\n" % myresult[counter][y])
      y = y + 1
   counter = counter + 1

file.close()
```

This is what I concluded from the answers above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.